# formatting a string where variable does not always exist in Python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, formatting

In one of my projects, I'm trying to parse parcel numbers that sometimes do, and sometimes don't have lot extensions (a three digit code at the end). I could obviously make an if elif structure to handle cases where lot extensions aren't present, but I was hoping to satisfy my curiosity and get some feedback on more efficient ways to write the code.

In it's current state, I end up with an unwanted trailing dash on parcels without a lot extension: '00-000-0000-'

Final parcel number formats should be:

- 00-000-0000
- 00-000-0000-000

and the input pins look like:

```
pin_that_wont_work1 = '00000000'
pin_that_wont_work2 = '000000000'
pin_that_works1 =     '00000000000'
pin_that_works2 =     '000000000000'

import re

pattern = r'^(\d{1,2})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{3})?$'

def parse_pins(pattern, pin):
    L = [x for x in re.search(pattern, pin).groups()]
    return '{dist}-{map_sheet}-{lot}-{lot_ext}'.format(dist=L[0] if len(L[0]) == 2 else '0'+L[0],
                                                       map_sheet=L[1],
                                                       lot=L[2],
                                                       lot_ext=L[3] if L[3] else '')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

pin_pattern = re.compile(r'^(\d{1,2})(\d{3})(\d{4})(\d{3})?$')

pin_formats = {
    3: '{0:02d}-{1:03d}-{2:04d}',
    4: '{0:02d}-{1:03d}-{2:04d}-{3:03d}'
}

def parse_pin(s):
    groups = [int(d) for d in pin_pattern.search(s).groups() if d is not None]
    return pin_formats[len(groups)].format(*groups)
```

Comment: That's very concise. I was having IndexErrors when calling .format() on a list, which makes sense. Does the asterisk before *groups somehow take the variables out of the list?

Comment: @Jon: yes, that's exactly what it does, converts a list or sequence into positional parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, but couldn't you just put the dash inside the format call?

```
def parse_pins(pattern, pin):
    L = [x for x in re.search(pattern, pin).groups()]
    return '{dist}-{map_sheet}-{lot}{lot_ext}'.format(dist=L[0] if len(L[0]) == 2 else '0'+L[0],
                                                       map_sheet=L[1],
                                                       lot=L[2],
                                                       lot_ext='-{0}'.format(L[3]) if L[3] else '')
```

Answer (score 2):

Throw them in a list, and list_.join('-').  The list should have 3 or 4 values.

Comment: I considered using join, but I didn't go that direction because it would have required a conditional for the 0 that sometimes needed to be tacked on front.